# URL rewriting for video file htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want rewrite url

```
http://site.com/videoplayback?pkey=05131305222303&hkey=a7432d324546a9b2c24abb4e81a26e67&tkey=l4i5w5s444&fkey=05131305222303.mp4
```

to

```
http://site.com/videoplayback/051313052223030/a7432d324546a9b2c24abb4e81a26e67/l4i5w5s444/05131305222303.mp4
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^videoplayback/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ videoplayback?pkey=$1&hkey=$2&tkey=$3&fkey=$4 [L]
```

But always have error 404 when i try access to this url

```
http://site.com/videoplayback/051313052223030/a7432d324546a9b2c24abb4e81a26e67/l4i5w5s444/05131305222303.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^videoplayback/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).mp4$ /videoplayback?pkey=$1&hkey=$2&tkey=$3&fkey=$4 [L]
```

Made three changes (some may not be required)

1. Added .mp4 to the end of the rule
2. Added slash to the beginning of the redirect
3. Changed .* to [^/]+ for sanity

Comment: Yeah but sometimes i have .flv links, not always mp4

Comment: Then, you now need to update the .mp4 section of the rule to whatever fits your needs. One example would be `.(mp4|flv)` and another, can be `.(.*)`. Another option, is to remove this part altogether, but then you will also have to remove he ending $ that, in regular expression terms means line ends.

Comment: This is working fine
`RewriteRule ^videoplayback/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /videoplayback?pkey=$1&hkey=$2&tkey=$3&fkey=$4 [L]`

Comment: The last one should not be ([^/]+) but (.*). If you use ([^/]+) you can append a / and then anything you like after a valid URL and it will still work. That is not the way URLs are supposed to work.